# possible to use font avsome icons in asp.net buttons

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, button, font-awesome

I can style a asp.net button using bootstrap, but is it somehow also possible to use font awsome icons together with some text so that I get a result like the one here http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/examples/ (see buttons section)?

Comment: Yes, just use the HTML and CSS given in the documentation?

Comment: But this doesn not render correct... Text="Search <i class='iconsweets-magnifying iconsweets-white'></i>"

Comment: It worked if I used Linkbuttons instead. :)